# Trino parser doesn't support lowercase keyword

Tags: presto, trino

I copied the SqlBase.g4 file from the Trino project to generate sql parser.However,It seems that the parser dosen't support the lowercase keyword like 'select'.Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the parser with a CaseInsensitiveStream. See https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/master/core/trino-parser/src/main/java/io/trino/sql/parser/SqlParser.java#L111

```java
SqlBaseLexer lexer = new SqlBaseLexer(new CaseInsensitiveStream(CharStreams.fromString(sql)));
CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
SqlBaseParser parser = new SqlBaseParser(tokenStream);
```

There's also additional setup you need to do for proper error handling and reporting, so take a look at the `SqlParser.java` class for how it's done.

Comment: Thank you.I have another question.I found that in CaseInsensitiveStream.java https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/77e6792a4304766e3c90f263d9e050eed4aad9ba/core/trino-parser/src/main/java/io/trino/sql/parser/CaseInsensitiveStream.java#L43.The SQL was turned into uppercase.That does solve the keyword problem.However,if there are strings inside the SQL,like`in("xxx","yyy","ZZ')`,it will be translated into `IN("XXX","YYY","ZZ")`,which is incorrect,how to solve it?

Comment: or maybe String isn't case-sensitive in trino?

Comment: No, they don't get converted to upper or lower case. Only the *matching* of keywords is performed using case-insensitive semantics.